# django content type and file size restriction

Tags: django, python-2.7

--**models.py**--

```
class resmodel(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    file_header = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upload_file = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
                    upload_to='documents', ]
                    content_types=['documents/msword', 'documents/pdf', 'documents/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'],
                    max_upload_size=5242880,blank=True, null=True)
    imag = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

--**views.py**--

```
def resview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        lname = request.POST.get('lname')
        file_header = request.POST.get('file_header')
        upload_resume = request.FILES['upload_resume']
        imag = request.FILES['im']

        if upload_file and imag:
            details = resmodel(file_header=file_header, fname=fname, lname=lname, upload_file=upload_file, imag=imag)
            details.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/save/success/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('file.html')
```

--**file.html**--

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<table border="0" align="center" cellsapcing="1" cellspadding="1">

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h3> Personal Information</h3></td>

        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
        <td>Resume Header<sub>(250 words max)</sub></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="file_header"></td>
        <td>Upload Resume<sub>(.doc/.docx, rtf, pdf, txt)</sub></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="upload_resume" ></td>
        <td>Upload image</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="im" ></td>

        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="reset" value="RESET">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

For "ContentTypeRestrictedFileField" i followed [this link](http://nemesisdesign.net/blog/coding/django-filefield-content-type-size-validation/)

But here i am able to upload all files and folders in both imag and upload_file field.
How to restrict this? Could anyone help me to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use form validation.

```
from django.forms import models as model_forms

def resview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_class = model_forms.modelform_factory(resmodel)
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            details = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/save/success/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('file.html')
```

But pay attention that this is basic form usage.

In future you should to pass form to template context and fill template with form data to display form inputs, labels and validation errors.

More documentation here [Creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/)
and here [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/)

Comment: WHAT IS THERE IN RESTRICTING CONTENT TYPE WITH THE ONE U GAVE ABOVE(VALIDATING FORM). PLEASE UNDERSTAND MY QUESTION.

Comment: The point of using a form is that it takes care of validation and data conversion. Form will restrict files with wrong content types for ContentTypeRestrictedFileField fields.